# Issue with encoding

Tags: html, utf

My html is in utf-8, as is my sql and my tables. But my variables are not saving latin characters. Is as if the post variables are changing the characters before sending it to my database.

Comment: Please provide more information like parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was sending my information via ajax, and I didn´t defined UTF-8 on ajax. I solved the problem by adding xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"); on my Ajax script